# How stop SetState flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I work on flutter project . when i click to modify icon to edit name for example ==> the screen is roaleded automatically . How i can stop refresh screen after click on edit button ?

this piece of my Form code :

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
        Text('Adresse email :',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF4053FCF),
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
            ),
        ),
        IconButton(
            icon: Icon(CommunityMaterialIcons.pencil,
            color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
                emailNode.requestFocus();
                setState(() {
                    enableemail = true;
                });
            })
    ],
),

  void editUserProfile() async {
    setState(() {});

    // if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    String name = _nameController.text;
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String adress = _adressController.text;

    userApi.editUserProfile(name, email, adress).then((data) {
      print(data);
      if (data != null) {
        //   Navigator.pop(context);

        /*  Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profile()));*/
      }
      //  setState(() {});

      /* Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BoxSettings()));*/

      setState(() {
        enableup = false;
        enableadress = false;
        enableemail = false;
      });

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(data)));

      // ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar3);
    }).catchError((error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.toString())));
    });
    setState(() {});
  }
```

and this my screen for more information :

[image]

How i can press on edit button without reload screen ?

Comment: do you mean that the application reload ? Is there any error ?

Comment: the screen is refresh automatically

Comment: not error but inused action (refreshing screen)

Comment: So you only want to refresh the button and not the whole screen ?

Comment: yes ... excatly i want to refresh input text only for add new name . after editing input the screen will refresh after

Answer (score 1):

There some workarounds to achieve this (i.e. update the state of one widget after tapping a completely different widget) like passing the callback function as a parameter etc.

But The best and neat solution here which will solve the above problem and keep your code neat is using Provider pattern.

If you are not aware of how a Provider pattern works, you can easily google search for articles regarding it. Here is one of them :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/6373413-state-management-with-provider

Read the above article before moving below.

Basically what we do is :

Create a ChangeNotifier class.

Wrap the parent of both widgets by a ChangeNotifierProvider widget.

Wrap the widget you want to update with Consumer widget.

Then in your onTap/onPressed function of Edit button you can call a function which will call the notifyListener() function. What this will do is it will notify the above ChangeNotifierProvider widget that some change has neen occured in it's widget tree. Then it will traverse the child whole widget tree below and will update the widget wrapped with Consumer widget.

So this way, you wont need to refresh your whole screen and you can easily update one widget by doing some action on a competely different widget.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the widgets you want to refresh inside stateful builder and make the whole screen a stateless widget and then call stateful builder

Comment: This is good if you want to update the same widget you pressed. If you want to update some other widget, you should consider other solution like using a provider.

Comment: Why not just build all widgets to be updated in a single column inside a stateful builder ?

Comment: This can be considered as one scenario where only the widgets your want to refresh are being grouped in a group widget like Row,Column or a Stack. Forcing widgets in a group widget just to refresh them specifically might not be a good option as group widget are not exactly made for that purpose but are made solely as UI elements.

Comment: One of the many example of above can be : say you have a column of 10 red colors containers and a button at the end. But you only have to update the color of last 3 containers after pressing the button. In this case you will have to nest a seperate column containing the last 3 containers and the button, inside your actual column. We can see that it's will not be a good practice. And say in the same above scenario, if you have to update color of alternate containers of the column instead of last 3, it will not  be a feasible option.

Comment: Ok Makes sense .

Comment: - @Sarvesh Dalvi . I can't resolve this problem until now . when i click on edit icon ==> the all screen reloaded.  I want to refresh the input only for editing value . how i can do it ?

Comment: Did you check the solution I posted ? It will solve your problem

Comment: can you help me to check the solution ?first , How i can wrap the  widgets ?@Sarvesh Dalvi